# How could I know the version of gcc is 64-bit or 32-bit?

Tags: gcc

I am using windows 7 64-bit. I don't know the gcc installed on this computer is 32-bit or 64-bit. (Windows 7 support both 32- and 64-bit programs).

Comment: Thank you. That works! I kept trying gcc --version and could not figure out. Here is the information I got, which turns out to be a 32-bit gcc: 
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.7.0 20111220 (experimental) (GCC)

Comment: Conversely, that's exactly a 64-bit version (`x86-_64`)...

Comment: Ah, my mistake. There's a lot I need to learn. Thanks again! You answered my question instantly, I wish I could mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can inspect the output of `gcc -v` or you can use the more direct option `-dumpmachine`. The first option allows you to discover if GCC is capable of multilib (so that it can compile both 32 and 64-bit binaries), the second option will only return the default target (if I am not mistaken).

Comment: Just to add some details... I have tested on Windows with gcc -dumpmachine. In 32 bits, it says mingw32 and in 64 bits it says x86_64-w64-mingw32

Answer (score 0):

write a c code as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
    int*pointer;
    printf("%d", sizeof(pointer));
    
}
```

then compile and run this

if the output shows 8, then the compiler version is 64 bit
else if the output shows 4, then the compiler version is 32 bit
the size of the c pointer is equal to the compiler version

8 means 8 bytes= 64bit

4 means 4 bytes= 32bit