# Check which version of g++ being used

Tags: g++

I have both 32 and 64 bit g++ installed on my server and when compiling I want to make sure that I am compiling in 64 bit mode, when I do `g++ --version` I don't get information about which architecture package I installed, is there a way I can check command line with g++ to see if it is using the 64 bit version.

I need the 32 bit version for other dependencies so its not an option to remove that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How could I know the version of gcc is 64-bit or 32-bit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19652212/how-could-i-know-the-version-of-gcc-is-64-bit-or-32-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
~$ g++ -dumpmachine 
x86_64-linux-gnu
```